# Can we alter the data members of base class from a derived class?

Tags: c++

```
struct A
{
    int a = 90, b=  87, c = 23;
};

struct A1 : public A
{
   int a1 = a;
};

struct A2 : public A
{
   int a2 = b;
};

struct A3 : public A
{
   int a3 = c;
};

struct R : public A1, public A2, public A3
{
    int r = a1 + a2 + a3;
};
```

This gives me the perfect output. But, I would like to know if we can give values to a, b, c in the derived structs. And the reason too. Thank you! :)

Comment: What do you mean by `give values to a, b, c in the derived structs`, when would you like to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, unless the base class marks the variables as private. But in structs the members are public be default (which is also why you can assign the members in the derived classes with values of the base classes).

You are asking for a reason why this possible. If the answer "they are public be default in structs" is not clear there is probably a deeper misunderstanding of oop generics.